# Definition of Data flow and sequencing graphs.

Tags: graph-theory, definition

I'm reading a book that provides a bit of back ground of graph theory. There are a couple of definitions I don't understand.

> A data-flow graph $G_d(V,E)$ is a directed graph whose vertex set 
>   $V = \left\{ v_i \;;\; i = 1,2,...,n_{ops} \right\}$ is in one-to-one
>   correspondence with the set of tasks.

Later the following definition is given

> A sequencing graph $G_s(V,E)$ is a hierarchy of directed graphs. A
>   generic element in the hierarchy is called sequencing graph entity

It then specifies

> A sequencing graph is an extended data-flow graph that has two kinds
>   of vertices: operations and links, the latter linking other sequencing
>   graph entities in the hierarchy.

An example is provided

> Let us consider first a sequencing graph entity that has only
>   operation vertices, e.g., a non-hierarchical model or an entity that
>   is a leaf of the hierarchi. The vertx set $V$ is in one-to-one
>   correspondence with the operations. The edge set $E$ models the
>   dependencies due to data flow or serialization. The graph has two
>   major properties. First, it is acyclic...

However a Dataflow graph has to be directed, and there are many directed graphs that can have cicles, right?

Am I missing something?

Comment: I think the author(s) may be implicitly assuming that data-flow graphs should be acyclic, because a cycle in the dependencies would make it impossible to run the process: at some point there is would be no viable execution path that would satisfy all the dependencies. Note, that I am only guessing (in particular you may have things like feedback loops, etc.), so please check this thoroughly, perhaps there are some hints in other parts of the book.

Comment: The book is this one by the way: http://unina.stidue.net/Architettura%20dei%20Sistemi%20di%20Elaborazione/Materiale/G.%20De%20Micheli%20-%20Synthesis%20And%20Optimization%20Of%20Digital%20Circuits%20(Text%20Recognized%20Using%20OCR)%20%5Bv.%201.03%2020-4-2005%5D.pdf the definitions are given in section 3.3.4.

Comment: I've reviewed the chapter two, where the graphs defintions are given, I still can spot why the graph in the given example should be acyclic. I've also seen two more books in google books, where the definition of dataflow graph is the same I've given, so I assume the defintions i reported is ok.

Comment: I've looked at the section 3.3.4 of the book you've linked, and I find it ambiguous and unclear. I would not assume any particular interpretation of that. If you have anybody directly related that could help you (like a professor), asking them would be the best bet. On the other hand, if you study on your own (or for whatever reason you would prefer another option), you could contact the original author, [Giovanni De Micheli](http://si2.epfl.ch/~demichel/).